# Errors submitting to Arxiv - several issues

Tags: errors, arxiv

I am trying to submit an article to Arxiv and getting some latek related errors! I made the paper in overleaf and then clicked submit and submit to arxiv and downloaded the zip file it generated with the .bbl file! Now im getting all kinds of issues: can anyone help? error pasted below! It really seems mad at "! LaTeX Error: File `tabularray.sty' not found."

Processing Status: Failed

If you are attempting to compile with a specific engine (PDFLaTeX, LaTeX,
TeX) please carefully review the appropriate log below.

Summary of attempted TeX compilation runs:

```
  Processing;'neurips_2023.tex'
    Running latex for first time.
    Running pdflatex for first time.
    Running tex for first time.
  Processing;'02_Exp.tex'
    Running tex for first time.
  Processing;'03_Results.tex'
    Running tex for first time.
  Processing;'extratables.tex'
    Running tex for first time.

  Last run per file and engine
    neurips_2023.tex:
      Last run for engine latex is first
      Last run for engine pdflatex is first
      Last run for engine tex is first
    02_Exp.tex:
      Last run for engine tex is first
    03_Results.tex:
      Last run for engine tex is first
    extratables.tex:
      Last run for engine tex is first

Key for Highlighted AutoTeX Log:
Severe warnings/errors.'
Warnings deemed important'
General warnings/errors from packages.'
Warnings/Errors deemed unimportant. Example: undefined references in first TeX run.'
Indicates positive event, does not guarantee overall success
Informational markup
References to arXiv help pages or other documentation.
Highlighted AutoTeX Log:

[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2020 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <01_introduction.tex> is of type 'unknown'.
[verbose]: <02_Exp.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <03_Results.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <04_Discussion.tex> is of type 'unknown'.
[verbose]: <05_Checklist.tex> is of type 'unknown'.
[verbose]: <LaMDA_LRS2.png> is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <extratables.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <neurips_2023.bbl> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <neurips_2023.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <neurips_2023.tex> is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: <references.bib> is of type 'BiBTeX'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'neurips_2023.tex'
[verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running latex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4902658/ && latex 'neurips_2023.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./neurips_2023.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./neurips_2023.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))

! LaTeX Error: File `tabularray.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.39 ^^M

No pages of output.
Transcript written on neurips_2023.log.

[verbose]: latex 'neurips_2023.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4902658/ && pdflatex 'neurips_2023.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./neurips_2023.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./neurips_2023.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))

! LaTeX Error: File `tabularray.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.39 ^^M

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on neurips_2023.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'neurips_2023.tex' failed.
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4902658/ && tex 'neurips_2023.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./neurips_2023.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
{article}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
{article}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on neurips_2023.log.

[verbose]: tex 'neurips_2023.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'neurips_2023.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file '02_Exp.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4902658/ && tex '02_Exp.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./02_Exp.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \section
{Experimental Design:}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \section
{Experimental Design:}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on 02_Exp.log.

[verbose]: tex '02_Exp.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file '02_Exp.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file '03_Results.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4902658/ && tex '03_Results.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./03_Results.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \section
{Results:}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \section
{Results:}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on 03_Results.log.

[verbose]: tex '03_Results.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file '03_Results.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'extratables.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4902658/ && tex 'extratables.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./extratables.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \begin
{table}[h]
?
! Emergency stop.
l.2 \begin
{table}[h]
No pages of output.
Transcript written on extratables.log.

[verbose]: tex 'extratables.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'extratables.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: tabularray is a rather new package, and the texlive system on arxiv is rather old. They announced to update to texlive 2023 in a few days: https://blog.arxiv.org/2023/05/12/tex-live-2023-upgrade-to-occur-may-22nd-2023/ . So perhaps you should simply wait ...

Comment: Does the neurips style add the package for you, or are you explicitly adding it in the preamble, and (more critically) are you using the functions of the package? If you're not using it and the style file didn't load it you shouldn't include it in the preamble. A lot of conferences add things in that they think you _might_ need, but they're not using...

Comment: You can also download and include its corresponding .sty file: [tabularray.sty](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/blob/main/tabularray.sty) in your project. This way arxiv will be able to use it.

Comment: the texlive update is complete. Please try uploading your source again if you're still having difficulties please contact us through the support channel.